# how to get all datas in a mysql table with same id

Tags: php, mysql

I have something like that in my mySQL database:

[image: sql table]

(User 734 have many informations : biography, name, phone, mail ...)

I want to get an array (in PHP) with grouped datas :

```
array(
    [734]=>
    object {
        [155] => string "Dominique",
        [4] => int(047682037),
        [1] => string "Dominique B"
    },
    [735]=>
    object {
        [155] => string "Other",
        [4] => int(0123456789),
        [1] => string "Other B"
    }
)
```

not only for 734 user but for each user. With a simple query I get everything but not in the good order. Can I make it in SQL or I maybe need to rearrange datas in PHP next ?

What is the sql query to get, for each user_id, all the related datas ?

I can't change the database structure (WP and buddypress)
I can't use native WP functions (because getting datas from another site)

Comment: checkout this: http://blueskyworkshop.com/topics/PHP-Pages/getting-started-with-mysql/#SelectData

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM (whatever your table name is)
WHERE user_id = (whatever user id you're interested in getting data for)
```

Comment: Unfortunately with this query datas are not grouped. If I use GROUP BY problem is than every field is named "value" and is overide by next value.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. You asked for an SQL query to gather the data related to a specific user_id. If you want to gather all the data for each specific user_id, then you could gather a list of all user IDs and iterate over each user ID with the query I have provided.

Comment: Your query wont work for this specific example : its work for one line with an unique ID. Look well at the screenshot : there are multiples lines with same ID and row always named "Value" (The WordPress way of storing datas). I want the datas to be ordered like my example directly with SQL. For the moment I get the raw data and use PHP functions to rearrange objects and array. But its not clean.

Answer (score 1):

Solution using `ORDER BY` :

```
$users = array();
$current_user = null;
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT user_id, field_id, value FROM `TABLE_NAME` ORDER BY user_id, field_id");
while ($result && $row = $mysqli->fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if ($current_user != $row['user_id']) {
      $current_user = $row['user_id'];
      $users[$row['user_id']] = array();
    }
    $users[$row['user_id']][$row['field_id']] = $row['value'];
}
```

**EDIT** :

There is another solution using `GROUP BY` and `GROUP_CONCAT` :

```
$users = array();
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(field_id SEPARATOR '|') as fields, GROUP_CONCAT(value SEPARATOR '|') as values FROM `TABLE_NAME` GROUP BY user_id");
while ($result && $row = $mysqli->fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $fields = explode('|', $row['fields']);
    $values = explode('|', $row['values']);

    $users[$row['user_id']] = array();
    // Problem id you have your field ids and your values in separate arrays, not sure what you want to do with them
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE user_id = 734");
```

Or if you arent using mysqli:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE user_id = 734");
```

Comment: It's not working : I want to get data from all users. All the values are retrieved but not grouped. I want all datas from an user in the same row.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the PDO library you could check the PDO::FETCH_GROUP attribute.
http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

> **fetch_style:**
>   To return an associative array grouped by the values of a specified column, bitwise-OR PDO::FETCH_COLUMN with PDO::FETCH_GROUP.

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmt = $this->_mysqli->prepare('SELECT user_id,field_id,value FROM WHERE user_id = ?');

$stmt->bind_param('i', $user_id );
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($user_id, $field_id, $value);

while($stmt->fetch())
{
     $data[$user_id][$field_id] = $value;
}
```